# HTML images resized when page refreshes

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I'm working on a slideshow, and I'm getting a problem with the images being resized when the page refreshes. I've stripped my code down to the bare, gotten rid of all the javascript and as much of the html/css as I could while still getting the problem, and I simply cannot figure it out. The problem only arises on Safari. It doesn't happen every time I refresh, which makes it even more confusing.

I've posted a screenshot of how it should look, and then how it looks after I refresh the page. If you see anything in my code that could be causing this, please let me know.

[image: Correct View]
[image: Incorrect View]

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> Website </title>
<link href="slideshowRebuild.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="topDiv">
<iframe id="slideshowImg0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xKBqSeYgQwo" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div> <!-- topDiv -->  
<div id="imageDiv">
<table id="mediaMenu">
    <tr>
        <td class="subMenu"><img style="opacity:1.0" id="sub0" src="images/tebow.jpg" alt="Tim Tebow"></img>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu"><img id="sub1" src="images/nash.jpg" alt="Steve Nash"></img>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu"><img id="sub2" src="images/kobe.jpg" alt="Kobe Bryant"></img>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu"><img id="sub3" src="images/giants.jpg" alt="San Francisco Giants"></img>
        </td>
        <td class="subMenu"><img id="sub4" src="images/tbrown.jpg" alt="Terrell Brown"></img>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>  <!-- imageDiv --> 
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
body{
background-color:#CCC;
}
#imageDiv {
border: 5px solid black;
width:93%;
position:relative;
background-color:#E0EAFF;
margin:3%;
}
#mediaMenu, #mediaMenu table {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-spacing:0;
position:relative;
}
#mediaMenu td {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:20%;
}
#mediaMenu img {
width:100%;
height:90px;
}

#contentText {
color:orange;
float:right;
width:39%;
}
```

Comment: you have `width:100%;` for your `#mediaMenu img` selector, which is going to make your images resize. If you do not want them to resize use a static width and height

Comment: That was intentional. I wanted each image to take up the entire td cell. If I didn't have that, the images would expand beyond the size of the cell. But regardless, why would that cause the images to be about a pixel wide after some refreshes?